# How do I check if a value from an entry is in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Pokemon Damage Calculator/Battle Simulator in python. Being moderately experienced in the language, I know most of the jibe, however, I can't seem to figure out **how to retrieve an entry (the users choice of Pokemon) and check if it's in a list.** I will be using this function for a chunk of the script and I'm not sure how to code it.

I've tried a `if` statement combined with `.get` but, when I try that, the error `TypeError: 'set' object is not callable` appears.

Heres my code to show my situation:

```
from tkinter import *

Pokemon = {"Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur", "Charmander",
"Charmeleon", "Charizard", "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise",
"Caterpie", "Metapod", "Butterfree", "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedrill",
"Pidgey", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot"}

def begin():
    global battle
    if pokemon1.get() in Pokemon and pokemon2.get() in Pokemon():
      battle = Tk()
      battle.title("Battle")

root = Tk()
root.title("Select Pokemon")
root.geometry("600x400")

Label(root, text="Pokemon 1").pack()
pokemon1 = Entry(root)
pokemon1.pack()

Label(root, text="Pokemon 2").pack()
pokemon2 = Entry(root)
pokemon2.pack()

Button(root, text="Begin!", command=begin).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Its a bit chunky, but it's not much (I cut down on the size of the list). If I could get an answer that helps me fix this error I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Should be `pokemon2.get() in Pokemon`, not `Pokemon()`.

Comment: Why don't you use `OptionMenu` or `ttk.Combobox` instead of `Entry` to select pokemon?

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, that makes more sense. Thanks for the answer anyways, it might still help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
test = "Bulbasaur"
if test in Pokemon:
    print("Found")
```

This is the simplest way to find something in a list/set